# I2C line pulled low by MCP23017

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi, i2c, schematics, design-rules

A simple interface of MCP23017 with Rpi using I2C lines. Since there is already an internal pull-up resistor of 1.8k on rpi I didn't use any pull-ups n I2C lines.

Running `i2cdetect -y 1` on rpi I rarely receive any response from MCP23017. Most of the times it's unresponsive and while trying to debug it on HW level I observed:

1. SDA line show 3.3V sometimes and sometimes 0.5
2. SCL line is always 0.5 to 0.7.

When I remove the connection and test only on I2C lines of Rpi, it works as expected. I believe the schematic is fairly simple and should work.

I have created multiple boards and only 1 board works and only 1 MCP responds on the same.
I have tested with both; VCC = 5V & 3.3V but no change in observation.
I have been struggling with this for more than a week and I can't think of any potential root cause now.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Don't you have to turn on the pullup resistors in the rpi code? Are you doing that?

Comment: No i didnt do that. I assumed that calling the i2cdetect should take care of all the configuration.

Comment: I will search more on that.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the rpi, so it's possible it does.

Comment: just an FYI, this might help in the search:
http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/io-pins-raspbian/i2c-pins

Comment: Thanks for your comment issi, but I don't think it's configuration issue since I have already enabled that. And as I said....sometimes I do get response from MCP23017. And when I when when I directly connect logic analyser to rpi , waveforms appear as expected.

Comment: I think it's not the configuration but something wrong with my design itself. I will update the same in question.